# Isn't the measurement postulate irrelevant to Wigner's friend extended?

Tags: metaphysics, quantum-physics, quantum-interpretations

So many physicists like Carroll use a variation of Wigner's friend to argue for the many worlds of many worlds. I shall stick to the [Frauchiger and Renner version](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-05739-8) of the Wigner's-friend scenario which argues that quantum theory cannot be used to model physical systems that are themselves agents who use quantum theory.

Roughly speaking, those [assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_friend#An_extension_of_the_Wigner%27s_friend_experiment) are

- (Q): Quantum theory is correct.
- (C): Agent's predictions are information-theoretically consistent.
- (S): A measurement yields only
  one single outcome.

I don't see how (S) has anything to do with the paradox. I can reformulate the whole thing with density matrices and I still get a difference of descriptions in terms of density matrices.

What am I missing in my understanding?